# How to get text from a mouseover pop out message using playwright python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have a image with a pop up information, when the mouse is over the image it shows:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbDh9.png)

`::after` appears as i hoover it.
the html is:

```
<div class="cat87">&nbsp;</div>
```

i have tried everything, per example:

```
    nfo_genres = page.locator(".cat87")
    nfo_genres = nfo_genres.hover()
    print(nfo_genres)
```

can some one point me to the right direction, how to get the image name?

Comment: There is currently no way to get content for a pseudo elements like `div::after` in Playwright, you can file a feature request.